# Veritas Volume Manager on OpenSolaris

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

I downloaded:

http://download.oracle.com/otn/solaris/11/OracleSolaris11_11-11_VM.zip

and succesfully booted it! :) only two things needed to be changed: 512 MByte RAM and VBox Processor Execution Cap to 80%. But. I can't find any packages regarding Veritas Volume manager!

I searched: http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/en/index.shtml with no luck.

I tried a:

```
pkginfo | grep VRTS
```

as

http://www.unix.com/solaris/154779-vxvm-cluster-information.html

states, but I can't find any packages having "vx" in their names.

**Q:** How can I Install/use the Veritas Volume Manager on OpenSolaris? Wikipedia states that Vertias is available on OpenSolaris too, not just Solaris!

Comment: Veritas Manager product is from Symantec and is not shipped with Opensolaris/Solaris. If you are looking for the solution, I would be looking at using Zpool stuff with ZFS filesystem.

Comment: VX is part of Solaris. http://www.blight.com/~rick/veritas/cheat.html

Comment: It is definitely not. VXFS/VXVM are third party commercial products as Mat already answered.

Comment: @LanceBaynes the difference is, its available for installation on Solaris, and it is not default shipped with Solaris installer disks. part of Solaris, does not mean that it is shipped by the packager Sun/Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your setup, there's a legal way of running Veritas Volume Manager on Solaris if you don't mind a power-consuming, noisy, and heavy hardware dongle dubbing as a FC-AL disc array:
The A5000 Disc enclosure series named "Photon" had a VxVM license attached to it. You will need a matching and supported FC-AL adapter, and one of these beasts with at least one working disc in it. Transportation is probably the most expensive part involved in acquiring one.

Attach, install, and check with

```
lunatic$ vxlicense -p
vrts:vxlicense: INFO: Feature name: SSA [99]
vrts:vxlicense: INFO: Number of licenses: 99
vrts:vxlicense: INFO: Expiration date: No expiration date
[...]
```

Once the hardware dongle is unplugged/switched off/dead/... an expiration date gets set and the day counter starts ticking, until the array gets connected and powered on again.

That's about the cheapest you can get. If I recall correctly, it didn't support all possible configurations though.

Answer (score 3):

Veritas Volume Manager is a proprietary product sold by Symantec, it's not an Oracle product or a Solaris feature. It is part of the [Veritas Storage Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veritas_Storage_Foundation) software stack, and is not freely available (AFAIK).

You might be able to get a trial version from the [Business - Storage Foundation](http://www.symantec.com/business/storage-foundation) page, but this is definitely in the "Enterprise Software" category, not something you'd use at home.

(Solaris 11 has [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) which has most of the features you'd use a volume manager for on a home/small server environment.)

Comment: So I have to pay for Veritas to get Veritas volume manager on OpenSolaris? Where?

Comment: You have to pay to get it for any OS. There's a direct link to the right part of the Veritas website in my answer. I believe you'll need to go through a reseller.

Comment: I can see that there is a trial version. I wonder how is it restricted vs. the paying version